# how to center perfectly image and text inline in the center of page

Tags: html, css, image, text, center

How to center perfectly both an Image and Text in the middle of container?

My task is to center in the footer side the logo and copyright text horizontally perfect. Please, share your CSS experience to similar task.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post your codes and provide a fiddle. It will be easier to answer..

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I do not have a specific code... just a second, I will add kind of example

Comment: do you use bootstrap or pure?

Comment: margin:0 auto; creates two lines: one line with image and another one with text..  but I want text and image to be inline...

Comment: @JeanGkol - it can be bootstrap too... but not exactly necessary

Comment: Have you tried floating the image and text to different sides?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically/19461564#19461564

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/tbj3hsmL/

HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" />
    <span class="text">Footer Text</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ddd;
    text-align: center;
}
    .footer img {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .footer .text {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: Happy to helo you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just make a div of what you want to center and in the css do like this:

```
margin:0;
```